# External monitor suddenly requires UHD Color

Tags: boot, dual-boot, multiple-monitors

HP Evo 16GB RAM, dual boot UEFI with Secure Boot. I upgraded dual-boot Windows to v 11, since then there is a flip-flop, every time I want to boot Ubuntu with external Samsung TV UN55NU (says HDR-capable) I have to set the "UHD Color" to enabled to see what the laptop is displaying. Intel 620 HD video, 3d party drivers were installed. I may try booting off the LiveUSB and see if video is displayed that way. It used to display OK when warm-booted from Windows 10, this doesn't seem to happen any longer.

Comment: There are no 3rd party drivers for Intel Graphics

Comment: What is the exact question you are asking?

Comment: Question is: what is there in the driver for Intel 620 that seems to require me to go into settings and change UHD from off (Windows and Manjaro GNome seem to want it off) and keep it from appearing until it is enabled in the TV's settings, pretty much all flavors of Ubuntu (Kubuntu/Budgie/VanillaU) that seem to not display anything (TV displays HD1 no input detected) until I turn UHD on?? Samsung UN55NU6950 is the Smart TV model, it is a USA model if that matters.  

And, while it may not be there aren't Intel 3rd Party Drivers, it could be that installation in 3rd Party "mode" contributes?